# Uploading large file to S3/D42 as parallel multipart with python boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, multipart

I am trying to upload a 400 GB .ibd file of MySql DB machine into D42/S3.

I am using `set_contents_from_file` function of Python boto. But it is taking a lot of time and I cannot see the progress (about how much uploaded/left).

Does anyone have any python script to use thread or parallel multipart upload? It's a very simple use case for end-user, but boto's [documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html) doesn't have any function like this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it with '[S3cmd](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd-howto)' and not with python.